# Using HTML & Php together?

Tags: php, html, css, web

I am required to make a website which supports some basic functions like download/upload.
So far I have only done the designing using basic HTML, CSS & Jquery functions..
However i have been asked to incorporate another students website within mine.. which  performs functions like .. uploading documents, create new data specimen, update etc.. He has made his website completely on PHP .. 
I would like help in understand how to combine his work with whatever i have gotten so far?

Comment: Go to Amazon and get a good PHP book.

Comment: No one can explain in 1 answer how you can do this, you simply need to learn PHP. Either buy a book or watch videos online. There are many PHP tutorials on youtube and some really good step by step tutorials on asklinda.com

Comment: Check my answer, it might help you out (though your project(s) may be designed in such a manner that implenting this would become a hassle. It might be handy for future reference ;)) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10732207/1294864

Comment: This question is just a bit too vague to be of use to future visitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sure combine both of them.

PHP (and any other server side technology) is made to generate HTML contents and processing it on the server before returning the output to the client's web browser.

I **Strongly** suggest that you learn PHP, at least the fundamentals. then you will get the whole idea; but to make things clear for now (Even though I don't think they will be clear until you learn PHP first) let me show you how to combine PHP and HTML as quick examples:

1- You can combine them with PHP echo statement like this:

```
 <?php 
 echo "<html>";
 echo "<title>HTML with PHP</title>";
 echo "<b>My Example</b>";

 //your php code here
 // Or you can use the print command

 print "<i>Print works too!</i>"; 
 ?>
```

There is also another way(s) like:

2- Embedding PHP code within HTML

```
 <html> 
 <title>HTML with PHP</title>
 <body>
 <h1>My Example</h1>

 <?php
 //your php code here
 ?>

 <b>Here is some more HTML</b>

 <?php
 //more php code
 ?>


 </body>
 </html>
```

However, trust me on this, you will get a better idea of what is going on when you learn PHP as I mentioned above. Plus, there are couple of resources in the internet to start learning PHP from. (Google is your friend!)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the example (i dint know it was possible to have php inside html) :) .. I will start learning PhP on w3schools

Comment: You are very welcome and just to help you on PHP Development, [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php) is your friend, in there you can find any thing related to PHP functions, classes and so on in there.

Good Luck in PHP!
^_^

Answer (score 3):

PHP is often used to generate HTML, so you can use it wherever you would normally use HTML. Feel free to mashup the code as much as you like (within reason), and it should work fine.

I would suggest getting this other student to help you though. If they created PHP they probably know a bit more about website creation than you do.

Comment: Well .. I'm doing internship and that student has left really long  before i joined.. so I'm just given a bunch of his php codes and i'm not sure where to begin

Answer (score 1):

- Host your site on a server which uses Apache webserver so as your PHP pages will be compiled on server-side.
- Rename all your .html pages to .php pages in which you want to include some php logic.
- Embed your PHP code inside `<?php` and `?>` tags inside your PHP pages.
- Use separate PHP files for connection, functions etc.
- If your're confused, then you'll find [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/) basic tutorial on PHP helpful.

Comment: Thank you vishal .. I have the apache webserve running.. and have been able to get .sql files for the tables the other student has used..Some of my pages will be static html.. Is it okay to leave it as html and have other as php?

Comment: You can keep those with .html extension, but I recommend you renaming every html page with .php extension as it will allow you to put your PHP code anytime in it.

Answer (score 0):

Just design the page in HTML and rename it to php. Do whatever php functions you want inside

```
<?php

?>
```

The script outside this nesting will be displayed as html. If you want to display anything inside `<?php ?>`, just use `echo`, `print` or `printf`

You may have a look at **[here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100512235357AAy074C)** for their difference.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things I don't see mentioned here is a templating engine, which are actually quite handy when it comes to seperating PHP from HTML.
I use Smarty myself. The good thing about templating engines is that you can really seperate the templates (HTML) from PHP. So the designer hardly needs to know any PHP functions, and the PHP programmer only needs to worry about functionality and not design.
The PHP programmer (using smarty in this case) assigns the values to be displayed to the smarty template and then the designer just includes these variables in his normal HTML. Works like a charm if you ask me and doesnt really require lots of code changes if done right (not sure in this case).

[Smarty templating engine](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 0):

for the starting of PHP ,i think the best path is http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp ,if you want to add the pages of your student than,check out that the page static or dynamic,if the pages are static (fully HTML) than you don't have to do any thing ,just save those pages as .php extension,and if there is dynamic pages(connected from database) than you should have much knowledge of basic php.